# Management Studio has any logging mechanism for user actions

Tags: ssms

Exists any possibility to instrument "Management Studio" to log all user actions that are performed? Eg. search, modify data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS does not have this functionality.
I develop SSMSBoost add-in for Management Studio and have recently added this functionality.
Have a look here:

http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-executed-sql-statements-logging-history

Additionally it can also keep history of SQL Editor window. It helps sometimes to restore lost work after unexpected shut-downs.